# How Do I handle IOErrors From HTML Enabled Text Fieds in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling, textfield, htmltext, ioerror

If I'm loading images via the <img> tag in a dynamic text field and an IOError is thrown, what would I attach the event listener too?  the text field?
I tried this...

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.htmlText = "here is some text <img src='image.jpg'> and then some more";
textField.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IOError, function (e:Event):void { trace("error caught") });
```

to no avail...

Suggestions?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309713/flash-textfield-html-how-do-i-prevent-the-error-dialogue-for-missing-images-e

I didn't actually test the solution I accepted (no time at the time), so let me know if it does/doesn't work for you. (Edit: Okay, I'm not that lazy, I'm trying it out...)

Comment: looks like you promised to test it in may last year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set an `id` to `img` and then use it within [getImageReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c83.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c65) on your `TextField` to get the `Loader` where you can add all the [Event](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html) you want:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

//...
var tfd:TextField = new TextField();
tfd.htmlText = 
      "here is some text <img id='myImg' src='image.jpg' /> and then some more";
var ldr:Loader = tfd.getImageReference("myImg") as Loader;
if (ldr != null) {
 ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
}
//...
private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
 //...
}
```

Another example [here](http://wiki.mediaboxtraining.com/doku.php/flash:text_loading) if you want

Answer (score 2):

i've solution for ya:

```
tField.addEventListener( Event.ADDED, addedObjectToFieldHandler, true );

function addedObjectToFieldHandler( event:Event ):void
{
   if ( event.target is Loader )
   {
       ( event.target as Loader ).contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function( e:IOErrorEvent ):void{} );
   }
}
```

that will prevent flashplayer from throwing errors and crash whenever image link is broken

Comment: This works and in my opinion a better solution, because you do not have to know the id..

Answer (score -1):

you have to use a try catch block:

```
try
{
  var textField:TextField = new TextField();
  textField.htmlText = "here is some text <img src='image.jpg'> and then some more";
}
catch( error:IOError )
{
    //handle IOError
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, thus the question (and the question it duplicates)